# Creating new web application using WFE server

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, navigation, alternate-access-mapping, dns

I have deployed a SharePoint 2013 server farm with a web server (WFE1), an application server (WApp1) and a sql server. At first, WFE1 and WApp1 worked as  application server and as web server, but i decided implement a three-tier server farm. The question is the next one, when i creating a new web application, the url that appear for that web application is the url of WApp1 instead of WFE1, how i fix that problem. Temporarily i manually fix, but i wish resolve this issue in an automatically way.

Answer (score 1):

You will find it easier if you setup DNS entries for your web application urls. This will help if you need to change servers in the future etc. That way they will be set automatically (in future, set your host header value while creating the web application).

You can still modify this now.  First create a DNS entry (for example myintranet.contoso.com) which points to the WFE1 server.

Once that is done, go to Central Administration and Alternate Access Mappings. Select your web application, and click Edit Public Url.  Set it to the DNS entry name.

You should now see the web application Url as the DNS entry instead of the server name, and also be able to access it via DNS too.

This Technet article explains [Alternate Access Mappings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263208.aspx).

Comment: Thanks so much, i can't change any DNS entries because my enviroment of work does not allowed me for security reasons, but by reading your suggestions I was thinking i can fix my bit trouble by changing the WApp1's url in the alternative access mapping interface, but that does not resolve anything, the url of WApp1 still appears when I creating a new web application, however when I change the default port of that new web application, everything work as I expected, the url of that web application change immediatly to the url of the server that perform as WFE

Comment: Glad to hear you found a path forward, every environment is different. :)